# Why does slickgrid add 1000px in JS, then reverse it in CSS style?

Tags: slickgrid

When calculating the avaialable space for headers, slickgrid carefully measures each column, then adds `1000`.

```
function getHeadersWidth() {
  var headersWidth = 0;
  for (var i = 0, ii = columns.length; i < ii; i++) {
    var width = columns[i].width;
    headersWidth += width;
  }
  headersWidth += scrollbarDimensions.width;
  return Math.max(headersWidth, viewportW) + 1000;
}
```

When it puts it in the DOM, this 1000 is reversed out with CSS:

```
$headers = $("<div class='slick-header-columns' style='left:-1000px' />").appendTo($headerScroller);
```

You can see this live [in this example](http://mleibman.github.io/SlickGrid/examples/example1-simple.html), just inspect the `.slick-header-columns` element.

What I would like to know is, why? What does this css trick do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`git bisect` delivers the answer:

https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/commit/c299a5628c791a3b3cb390a22312eb2247b07cd5

Author: David Lee

Date:   Fri Mar 12 07:39:02 2010 +0800

Comment:

Improve column reorder behavior

Compatible with jquery-ui 1.8rc3

Columns can be dragged beyond the left edge, as can be done beyond the
right edge, so that columns can be dragged to the leftmost position,
even if the distance from the column's left edge to the initial
mousedown is greater than the distance between the left edge of the grid
and the midpoint of the previous leftmost column.

---

Notes:

1. The rationale is this:

   When you reorder the columns using the jQuery UI 'sortable' component, you, the user, can drag a column to the left and the leftmost column will move aside to give you room to preview the reorder action: that means columnn 0 will be, at least temporarily, positioned in *negative coordinate space* (left @ -columnwidth, right @ 0px=left viewport edge).

   Since SlickGrid allows for arbitrary width columns, which may be changed during the grid lifetime, David Lee (the author of the edit merged by Michael Leibman) apparently (I *assume* here; I didn't check his pull request or other source datums) used a worst-case column width assumption of 10000 pixels (see the `c299` commit) to give the SlickGrid init code a one-size-fits-all setup/init.

   See the next note for the commit when Michael Leibman changed this to the current -1000px value.
2. I had the same question for quite a while and couldn't find why -- earlier `git bisect` attempts misled me to https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/commit/f2d480ce959b9f8504f718d6f7a825782d488415 which only changes the negative offset by a decade, while I did not know SlickGrid internals well enough back then to confidently set up a proper `git bisect` to hunt this one down. (The real change was done back in the SlickGrid 1.x series and there was a *lot* of code changed then)

   Only now that I took out the -1000px myself and noted the column reordering getting worse, did `git bisect` help me dig up the relevant bit of history.
3. *Off topic*: using `git bisect` taught me once again that git considers `bad` to be 'the new situation' and `git bisect good` to represent the *old* situation: I had to remind myself this while using `git bisect` as here the *old* situation (when the -1000px/-10000px code was not part of SlickGrid yet) was the 'bad' situation, at least to my mind. I.e. `git bisect bad` ~ 'this is like the new situation; `git bisect good` ~ 'this looks like the old situation'.

Comment: This is awesomely helpful Ger, thank you! Guess I need to put that back in unless we move away from jQuery UI sortable